# Can mutation rate be increased for instance by mutagenesis targeting the DNA polymerase?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, microbiology, mutations

I am studying a non-cultivable bacterium living in an insect host, and I would like to generate some random mutants of this bacteria while preserving the insect.

I am wondering if one way to do so might be to use directed mutagenesis directed towards the bacterial polymerase, which would leads it to increase the error rate.

- Does any one has already seen a study with this kind of approach?
- Does any one knows or guess another way to obtain some random mutants of the bacteria while preserving the host insect?